# I'm on Minecraft 1.8 but the game says I'm 1.7.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I would like to play Build Battle on Hypixels Minecraft Server which requires 1.8 to play. My Minecraft has told me that I am using the 1.8 version and it doesn't need to update when I load the launcher.

However, when I try to load Build Battle or any other new game on the server, it says I must be using 1.8. I don't know what to do, because I have already updated Java to the latest version, but the game still says to use 1.8.

I click on Versions and it says my latest one is 1.7.9. What can I do to play Build Battle?

Thanks for any answers that are given.

Comment: Are you using the new installer or the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Minecraft Launcher, you can create a new profile or edit an existing profile to change the version you play with on that profile.

The latest version of Minecraft is **1.8.7**, which works with the server, even on **Hypixels's Build Battle** game mode.

Try editing your profile by clicking on **`Edit Profile`** in the bottom left-hand corner of the launcher and checking the **`Use version:`** drop-down box to make sure you are using the latest version.

Alternatively, you can click **`New Profile`** to create a new profile for the server that uses the latest version.

When you click **`Play`**, if the version you selected is not yet installed, it will download and install it.

Comment: @WillCroot No problem!